# Print expression containing list variables in caller context

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to implement a command logger in TCL where each command is wrapped with prints and executed in caller context.

The method should also expand variables that refer to lists or list of lists by adding the `list` keyword in the right places.

For instance:

```
proc exec_cmd {cmd} {
   uplevel puts \"$cmd\"
   uplevel $cmd
}

proc somefunc {inlist1 inlist2} {
...
}

set x [list "P" "Q" "R"]
set y [list [list "A" "B"] [list "X" "Y"]]
exec_cmd {somefunc $x $y}
```

In the above example, I want the logger to print `[list P Q R]` and `[list [list A B] [list [X Y]]` in place of `$x` and `$y`

How can I do this?

This is what I've tried so far, but this doesn't work as I want it:

```
proc exec_cmd {cmd} {
    set stripped [string map {\" {} [ \[ ] \]} $cmd]
    uplevel puts \"$stripped\"
    uplevel $cmd
}
```

For the example above, the output I get is:

```
somefunc P Q R {A B} {X Y}
```

But what I want is:

```
somefunc [list P Q R] [list [list A B] [list X Y]]
```

Comment: Once `set x [list "P" "Q" "R"]` has been executed, you are left with `P Q R` as `$x`'s contents. I don't think there is any way to get back `[list P Q R]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method should also expand variables that refer to lists or list of
>   lists by adding the list keyword in the right places.

What is the objective, producing an executable snippet to replay a logged command execution? In any case, serialising a variable's value deemed a list using the [list] command form is not particularly meaningful for your logger. Besides, this is not possible in Tcl, after [list] execution, it is a list whatever its birth form (there are many ways how a Tcl value can become a list). It is a lost-form cast ...

> I'm trying to implement a command logger in TCL

Have you considered some built-in mechanism to set your expectations and/ or base your implementation on top of? [Execution traces](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9) will show you what you can expect from a logger's perspective:

```
% proc report args {puts [info level 0]}
% trace add execution somefunc enter report
% somefunc $x $y
report {somefunc {P Q R} {{A B} {X Y}}} enter
```

Re-implementing this on your own, doable, but tedious (e.g., you need to make sure that you don't produce side effects by preemptive command evaluation when preprocessing an intercepted command's argument).

Comment: Thanks for your response @mrcalvin. Yes, the objective is to produce an executable snippet for replay. Unfortunately I cannot use the `trace` package as I'm stuck with Tcl8.5 (toolchain issues).  Even if there was someway to enclose lists with `{}` I can post-process the log and make it executable. The problem I have now is that I don't see list boundaries with a simple `puts` command.

Comment: `trace` package? The `trace` command is available [for 8.5](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm).

Comment: oh oops, sorry you are right. it works. thanks so much for your help!